# How to convert PHAsset to PHLivePhoto

Tags: ios, objective-c, phlivephoto

I have `PHAsset` and I want to get `PHLivePhoto`.

`PHAsset` is `PHLivePhoto`'s asset.

I know this Function.

```
/// Requests a Live Photo from the given resource URLs. The result handler will be called multiple times to deliver new PHLivePhoto instances with increasingly more content. If a placeholder image is provided, the result handler will first be invoked synchronously to deliver a live photo containing only the placeholder image. Subsequent invocations of the result handler will occur on the main queue.
//  The targetSize and contentMode parameters are used to resize the live photo content if needed. If targetSize is equal to CGRectZero, content will not be resized.
//  When using this method to provide content for a PHLivePhotoView, each live photo instance delivered via the result handler should be passed to -     [PHLivePhotoView setLivePhoto:].
+ (PHLivePhotoRequestID)requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)fileURLs placeholderImage:(UIImage *__nullable)image targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize contentMode:(PHImageContentMode)contentMode resultHandler:(void(^)(PHLivePhoto *__nullable livePhoto, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

But I don't know use.

How to convert?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method from PHImageManager

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestLivePhotoForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize contentMode:(PHImageContentMode)contentMode options:(PHLivePhotoRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void (^)(PHLivePhoto *livePhoto, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler
```

Inside the resultHandler you obtain the PHLivePhoto ready to show in a PHLivePhotoView.

EXAMPLE:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestLivePhotoForAsset:asset targetSize:self.contentView.frame.size contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:nil resultHandler:^(PHLivePhoto * _Nullable livePhoto, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) { self.contentView.livePhoto = livePhoto  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
PHLivePhoto *livePhoto = [contentEditingInput.livePhoto];
}];
```